# Window Server Directory Permissions - Read-only folder w/full control subfolders

Tags: permissions

We have a directory on our Windows Server 2003 file server that contains subfolders for each one of our clients.  These are sub-divided alphabetically, so for example, we have a folder named "Clients A-C", etc.

Problem is, some users have a bad habit of accidentally moving the root folders, so A-C gets moved into D-H, for example.

How can I set the permissions on the top-level folders so that they cannot be moved, but still allow full control on the subfolders?

Answer (score 1):

Deny delete on the top level folder, set subfolders at next level down to not inherit and copy the permissions, then adjust to taste.